# Power Apps - generate days of month and exclude Holidays

Tags: powerapp, formula, collection

I'm creating App in Power Apps for generating Work days in `gallery`.

So I created a `collection`:

```
ClearCollect(colWorkDays,First('WorkDays'));
```

After that created an `array` with dates of Holiday:

```
Set(Holidays,[
     Date(2023,4,7),
     Date(2023,4,10)
    ]
);
```

Generated days without `weekends` for April:

```
ForAll(
    Switch(
        Text(DateValue(lblSelectedMonth.Text),"mm"),
         "04",[29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0],
If(
    Weekday(DateValue(lblSelectedMonth.Text) + Value - 1, 2) < 6,
    Collect(
         colWorkDays,{
         }
   )));
```

For Weekdays it works. But when I try add to `If` statement formula for `Holidays` it does not work:

```
If(
    Weekday(DateValue(lblSelectedMonth.Text) + Value - 1, 2) < 6
    And Not(DateValue(lblSelectedMonth.Text) - Value - 1 in Holidays),
```

Is there any chance to use If statement for removing Weekends and Holidays which are set in array?

Many thanks for any advice.